# Count instances of each unique integer in a vector in 1 line of code?

Tags: julia

Is there a slick way to rewrite this Julia function, perhaps using just 1 line of code, without making it much slower? (I just started using Julia. It's great!) `K` is a positive integer and `zd` is a vector of positive integers no greater than `K`. Thanks!

```
function tally(zd)
    ret = zeros(Int64, K)
    for k in zd
        ret[k] += 1
    end
    return ret 
end
```

Example:

```
julia> K = 5
julia> zd = [1,2,2,2,2,3];
julia> tally(zd)
5-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1
 4
 1
 0
 0
```

Comment: This seems pretty slick already.

Comment: I guess I had in mind a 1 line solution using something like `reduce` or `fold`, and I was also just curious about other approaches, but you're right, this may be good enough. And I like the suggestions below to use `hist`. I think I'll do that. Thanks all for the feedback!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't tested the performance, but using the hist function should work:

```
hist(zd,0.5:K+0.5)[2]
```

gives:

5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 4
 1
 0
 0

or, if the zeros are unimportant, just use

```
hist(zd)[2]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 4
 1
```

Answer (score 8):

Any alternative probably will not be faster. Your loop already does only one pass through the array. Julia loops are fast, and there is no speed advantage to vectorized code, as there is in other languages.

Have a look at Julia's implementation of the `hist` function. This is taken directly from the [Julia Standard Library](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/9a5c2768cb9c45b5931e8560c688ecf0eaa55fb7/base/statistics.jl#L153-L163):

```
function hist(v::AbstractVector, edg::AbstractVector)
    n = length(edg)-1
    h = zeros(Int, n)
    for x in v
        i = searchsortedfirst(edg, x)-1
        if 1 <= i <= n
            h[i] += 1
        end
    end
    edg,h
end
```

The "edg" parameter contains the edges of the bins. If we remove that feature, we get exactly the function you wrote.

**EDIT** `hist` has not been available in Julia Base since v0.5.0

Comment: FYI there may be speed advantages to vectorization as detailed here:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vectorization-in-julia
See also @simd here: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/performance-tips/ It's experimental in some cases and warns it may be removed..but given the performance benefits I doubt it.

Answer (score 8):

Here
http://statsbasejl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/counts.html#countmap

```
countmap(x[, wv])
Return a dictionary that maps distinct values in x to their counts (or total weights).
```

Answer (score 6):

There are [a bunch of counting functions](https://juliastats.org/StatsBase.jl/stable/counts/#StatsBase.counts) included in the [StatsBase.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/StatsBase.jl) package.  Your tally function is equivalent to `counts(zd, 1:K)`.

There are also methods for counting unique elements of types other than integer, too, such as `countmap`, which returns a dictionary mapping unique values to their number of occurrences.

Answer (score 5):

I know its old but how about

`[sum(zd .== i) for i in unique(zd)]`

in a short test it performed better than your initial function (time and memory wise).

Caution: result not sorted!