# The number of occurences of elements in a vector [JULIA]

Tags: vector, julia

I have a vector of 2500 values composed of repeated values and `NaN` values. I want to remove all the `NaN` values and compute the number of occurrences of each other value.

```
y
2500-element Array{Int64,1}:
8
43
NaN
46
NaN
8
8
3
46
NaN
```

For example:
 the number of occurences of 8 is 3
the number of occurences of 46 is 2
the number of occurences of 43 is 1.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172027/count-instances-of-each-unique-integer-in-a-vector-in-1-line-of-code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
y=rand(1:10,20)
u=unique(y)
d=Dict([(i,count(x->x==i,y)) for i in u])
println("count for 10 is $(d[10])")
```

Comment: it works. but l can't access to the array value by value, for instance (6,1) how can l read only then only 1 ?. l need that to draw a histogram. x-axis represents the different values and the y-axis is the number of occurnces of each value .[(i,count(x->x==i,y)) for i in u]
9-element Array{Tuple{Any,Int64},1}:
 (6,1) 
 (1,2) 
 (7,3) 
 (10,3)
 (9,3) 
 (2,3) 
 (5,1) 
 (3,2) 
 (8,2)

Comment: This works, and is very elegant. But it passes over the array `y` many times. If you have many unique values in `y`, it becomes unbearably slow, easily several orders of magnitude slower than necessary. `countmap` avoids this problem.

Comment: Not ruling out your comment (I actually didn't know about `countmap` and I'm checking out `StatsBase`), however, as you say so: "if you have". I'm convinced that premature optimization is evil and I'm a believer of ["the rules of optimization"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization)

Comment: Well, that's fair enough as a personal philosophy. I don't share the (apparently widespread) negative opinion of optimization. Furthermore, answers on Stackoverflow are visible for posterity, so I think that pointing out potential performance problems is a reasonable thing to do. Not all optimization is "premature", especially if it just involves applying general coding principles (e.g. "pass over an array just once.")

Answer (score 16):

To remove the `NaN` values you can use the filter function.  From the Julia docs:

> **filter(function, collection)**
>
> Return a copy of collection, removing elements for which function is false.

```
x = filter(y->!isnan(y),y)
filter!(y->!isnan(y),y)
```

Thus, we create as our function the conditional `!isnan(y)` and use it to filter the array `y` (note, we could also have written `filter(z->!isnan(z),y)` using `z` or any other variable we chose, since the first argument of `filter` is just defining an inline function).  Note, we can either then save this as a new object or use the modify in place version, signaled by the `!` in order to simply modify the existing object `y`

Then, either before or after this, depending on whether we want to include the `NaN`s in our count, we can use the `countmap()` function from StatsBase.  From the Julia docs:

> **countmap(x)**
>
> Return a dictionary mapping each unique value in x to its number of
>     occurrences.

```
using StatsBase
a = countmap(y)
```

you can then access specific elements of this dictionary, e.g. `a[-1]` will tell you how many occurrences there are of `-1`

Or, if you wanted to then convert that dictionary to an Array, you could use:

```
b = hcat([[key, val] for (key, val) in a]...)'
```

Note: Thanks to @JeffBezanon for comments on correct method for filtering `NaN` values.

Comment: Filtering with `y->y!=NaN` doesn't work, because `NaN!=NaN` is true (as per the rules of IEEE floating point arithmetic). Instead you can filter with `y->!isnan(y)`.

Comment: @JeffBezanson  Good catch, thanks!  I corrected it in the response.

Answer (score 6):

`countmap` is the best solution I've seen so far, but here's a written out version, which is only slightly slower. It only passes over the array once, so if you have many unique values, it is very efficient:

```
function countmemb1(y)
    d = Dict{Int, Int}()
    for val in y
        if isnan(val)
            continue
        end
        if val in keys(d)
            d[val] += 1
        else
            d[val] = 1
        end
    end
    return d
end
```

The solution in the accepted answer can be a bit faster if there are a very small number of unique values, but otherwise scales poorly.

**Edit**: Because I just couldn't leave well enough alone, here's a version that is more generic and also faster (`countmap` doesn't accept strings, sets or tuples, for example):

```
function countmemb(itr)
    d = Dict{eltype(itr), Int}()
    for val in itr
        if isa(val, Number) && isnan(val)
            continue
        end
        d[val] = get(d, val, 0) + 1
    end
    return d
end
```

Comment: Nice answer :) Why `get!` rather than `get`?

Comment: It's a pretty old answer, so I don't remember why I did this. You're right anyway, `get` is actually faster. `get!` will store the key in the dict if it's not already in there, but that's not needed in this case. I edited my answer, thanks for the tip!